# Drupal white screen after install "module list" module

Tags: error-handling, module, drupal-7

I installed and enabeled the "module list" module. After that I get the following error: **DOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /includes/lock.inc)**. There was no chance to go back to the backend, so I disabled the module in database. Now I get a blank screen and I turned on error reporting but nothing happens. When I try to use update.php in my browser I get this error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_default_format() in /sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/content_types/custom/custom.inc on line 19**. I searched for these errors but I found nothing which was helpful. I tried to clear cache from database but I have no clue what I could do. I don't backup the site before install the module, because everytime it helps to disable the module from database, so I really need a good solution without installing a new system or removing all of my configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Never use this module!! After hours I found out whats wrong with my system. The module disabled the filter-core module, which is default for drupal. I have no clue why there are not more reports for this issue. Maybe this was a problem with a combination of my modules but I think, that no module should be allowed to disable a core module like that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed by fixing the database connection details.